# jQuery button click to hide a div

Tags: jquery

I have a `<div>` which is hidden through jquery only inital when the page loads.
I have button, in which on the click event the `<div>` gets visible. I want the `<div>` to be hidden on the button click event also. I have a event on the button click binding a grid in asp.net.

Following is the code I have tried in which `#dInner` is the div and `#bNextWeek` is the button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dInner').hide();

    $('#<%=bNextWeek.ClientID%>').live('click', function (e) {
         $('#dInner').hide();                                
    });
});
```

Comment: From the code you have, you have actually hidden the `div` on page load itself (`$('#dInner').hide()`). So, you can't hide it again using click event!

Comment: thanks for the heads up will.i.am.... i made the div hidden through css and made it visible through jquery...worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$('#'+<%=bNextWeek.ClientID%>).live('click', function (e) {
        $('#dInner').hide();                                
});
```

or you can try with

```
$('#'+<%=bNextWeek.ClientID%>).live('click', function (e) {
       $('#dInner').css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: When i add the e.preventDefault(); my buttons onclick() event does not fire

Comment: the div gets hidden only initially for a second and again gets visible

Comment: made the div visible false through css and then made it visible through jquery..so the issue is resolved now..thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 0):

Try this.i will work.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $('#dInner').hide();

    $('#bNextWeek').live('click', function (e) {
        $('#dInner').css('display','none');

    });
```

});

Comment: What's the difference between `hide()` & `css('display','none')`?

Comment: made the div visible false through css and then made it visible through jquery..so the issue is resolved now..thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide and show the div element by the same button click in jquery, use toggle:
**$('#bttnId').bind('click', function () { $('#dInner').toggle(); });**

Comment: I made the div visible false through css display property and then made it visible through jquery..so the issue is resolved now..

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#dInner
{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#bNextWeek').live('click', function (e) {
    $('#dInner').css('visibility','visible');
    });

  });
```